# Creating a LOV of Database entries in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to make a form in APEX where you can link Contact entries from a database address table. Now I want the possibility in the form to select the contact linked from and select the contact linked to. 
I don't know if that's even possible to make a ListOfValue from Database entries?!
Thanx for your help..

Comment: It's certainly possible and it many forms. You can define select lists or use popup lovs or even plugins with expanded functionality. Your question is about real basic functionality however, and is covered in the 2-day developer guide. There is also the sample application provided by oracle (sample database application) which implements many of the basic features all around. You'd best be served by looking at those things first.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestions, but I looked already everywhere, in the developer guide and the sample application of course, and couldn't find it. But I'll keep on looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Sample Database Application, you can find examples of LOV usage:

- Page 7: `P7_CUST_STATE`, a select list where a Shared Component LOV is used
- Page 11: `P11_CUSTOMER_ID`, a popup lov where an SQL query is used

Comment: Thanx, this really helped.

Comment: @Sara These are the built-in solutions of course. Great to start you off. You can also look at how they work with an order entry in the sample application, as they go through a bit of a wizard. All good ideas. If you're looking for better LOV's you can always take a look at the skillbuilders super lov plugin, which is a community staple.

Comment: Ok, for sure I'll look. Thanx.